# MongoDB C# driver serializing lookup results

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, aggregation-framework

I am trying to populate a property on an object using a 'lookup' aggregation.  I can execute my aggregation as expected when I use MongoChef.  My C# code throws an exception when trying to deserialize the results.

I have Employer and Job collections in Mongo.  I have corresponding Employer and Job classes in C#.  The Employer is defined as having a CurrentJobs property that is of List type.

Both collections and objects share an EmployerId field.  My C# query (simplified):

```
      var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Employer>("Employer");
      collection.Aggregate().Lookup("Job", "EmployerId", "EmployerId", "CurrentJobs");
      employers = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

My objects (simplified):

```
public class Employer
{
  public List<Job> CurrentJobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    //various fields
}
```

My exception:

> An error occurred while deserializing the CurrentJobs property of
>   class My.Namespace.Employer: Cannot deserialize a 'List' from
>   BsonType 'Document'.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the exception coming from this line: `var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Employer>("Employer");`? Need more information because it appears you set up your POCO class incorrectly. I use MongoVUE and if it says "Array" then it will deserialize into a `List`, but regular "Document"'s deserialize straight into the POCO properties, and your exception says "BsonType 'Document'", not "Array" or "List".

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake.  I had assigned the CurrentJobs collection the data type of 'Object' in MongoDB.  I moved it to 'Array', and my deserialization errors disappeared.

I'm a moron...